# Convert enum to int in python

Tags: python, enums

I have an enum Nationality:

```
class Nationality:
        Poland='PL'
        Germany='DE'
        France='FR'
```

How can I convert this some enum to int in this or similar way:

```
position_of_enum = int(Nationality.Poland)  # here I want to get 0
```

I know that I can do it if I had code by:

```
counter=0
for member in dir(Nationality):
    if getattr(Nationality, member) == code:
        lookFor = member
        counter += 1
return counter
```

but I don't have, and this way looks too big for python. I'm sure that there is something much simpler .

Comment: A class is not an enum. Therefor you can't compare.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are better (and more "Pythonic") ways of doing what you want.

Either use a tuple (or list if it needs to be modified), where the order will be preserved:

```
code_lookup = ('PL', 'DE', 'FR')
return code_lookup.index('PL')
```

Or use a dictionary along the lines of:

```
code_lookup = {'PL':0, 'FR':2, 'DE':3}
return code_lookup['PL']
```

The latter is preferable, in my opinion, as it's more readable and explicit.

A `namedtuple` might also be useful, in your specific case, though it's probably overkill:

```
import collections
Nationalities = collections.namedtuple('Nationalities', 
                                       ['Poland', 'France', 'Germany'])
nat = Nationalities('PL', 'FR', 'DE')
print nat.Poland
print nat.index(nat.Germany)
```

Comment: you miss names of nationality. I must have them

Comment: @user278618 - I left them out for brevity. The idea was that you'd use a lookup table of some sort somewhere in your `Nationality` class. You could just as easily substitute in your class attributes, instead of strings.

Answer (score 144):

Please use [IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum)

```
from enum import IntEnum

class loggertype(IntEnum):
    Info = 0
    Warning = 1
    Error = 2
    Fatal = 3

int(loggertype.Info)
0
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: As of Python 3.4, this is the "more correct" answer (or, the guy who created the library, Ethan Furman's answer below).

Comment: In the above example you could also import auto, then initialize Warning, Error, Fatal, to auto().

Answer (score 40):

Using either the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) or [aenum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup> 
you can create a specialized `Enum`:

```
# using enum34
from enum import Enum

class Nationality(Enum):

    PL = 0, 'Poland'
    DE = 1, 'Germany'
    FR = 2, 'France'

    def __new__(cls, value, name):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member.fullname = name
        return member

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
```

and in use:

```
>>> print(Nationality.PL)
Nationality.PL
>>> print(int(Nationality.PL))
0
>>> print(Nationality.PL.fullname)
'Poland'
```

The above is more easily written using [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup>:

```
# using aenum
from aenum import Enum, MultiValue

class Nationality(Enum):
    _init_ = 'value fullname'
    _settings_ = MultiValue

    PL = 0, 'Poland'
    DE = 1, 'Germany'
    FR = 2, 'France'

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
```

which has the added functionality of:

```
>>> Nationality('Poland')
<Nationality.PL: 0>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer but I would like to get some details on what you are doing on `__new__` in `class Nationality(Enum)`: is `object.__new__` instantiating a new generic object and then setting its attributes? If so why you set `_value` but then it returns `value`? Why it does not work if I change from `fullname` to `name`?

Comment: @roschach: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 15):

```
from enum import Enum

class Phone(Enum):
    APPLE = 1 #do not write comma (,)
    ANDROID = 2

#as int:
Phone.APPLE.value
```

Need to access tuple by index if using commas:

```
class Phone(Enum):
    APPLE = 1, # note: there is comma (,)
    ANDROID = 2,

#as int:
Phone.APPLE.value[0]
```

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you just define the values as numbers instead of strings:

```
class Nationality:
    POLAND = 0
    GERMANY = 1
    FRANCE = 2
```

If you need to access the two-letter names, you can simply provide a table that maps them.  (Or a dictionary that maps the other way, etc.)

Comment: Don't do that because you can change it after definition without any sanity checks: `Nationality.GERMANY = 0`. This doesn't work in `enum`, it is WORM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many). The same goes with dicts. Enum is the right choice. :)

Answer (score 6):

One straightforward way to achieve this:

```
from enum import Enum

class Nationality(Enum):
    Poland= 1, 'PL'
    Germany= 2, 'DE'
    France= 3, 'FR'

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value[0]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value[1]

# Example use
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(int(Nationality.Poland))
    print(Nationality.Poland)
    print(int(Nationality.Poland) == 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> 1
>>> PL
>>> True
```

Explanation: You can create your enum with the desired numeration and string representation as you wish and you get the desired functionality by overwriting the respective `__int__` and `__str__` methods. To my knowledge, this does not break any contracts of `enum` and I prefer to keep functionality encapsulated in their respective classes.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Python does not store the order of class elements and `dir()` will return them in any order.

Seeing from your comment that you really do require a mapping from strings to integers, you should in fact do exactly that:

```
code_lookup = {
    'PL': ("Poland", 0), 
    'DE': ("Germany", 1), 
    'FR': ("France", 2), 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: I'm using this enum to set value of select which is at few sites with different css and language, and only value property is at each site the same. From this select I must select nationality, and values of options are 0,1,2. I use this casting in c#, so this is from I took this idea.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen something like:

```
PL, FR, DE = range(3)
```

Wrap it in a class and *viola*, you have a namespace for the enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

```
from enum import Enum

class Nationality(Enum):
    Poland = 'PL'
    Germany = 'DE'
    France = 'FR'

    @classmethod
    def get_index(cls, type):
        return list(cls).index(type)
```

and then:

```
Nationality.get_index(Nationality.Poland)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Nationality(Enum):
    Poland = 'PL'
    Germany = 'DE'
    France = 'FR'

    @property
    def ordinal(self):
        return list(self.__class__).index(self)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, index):
        return list(cls)[index]
```

and then:

```
>>> Nationality.Poland.ordinal
0
```

also

```
>>> Nationality.get(2)
Nationality.France
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This method is something I am using

```
from enum import Enum
ClientType_DICT = {
    "1": 'webapp',
    "2": 'application',
    "3": 'embedded'
}
ClientType_ENUM: Enum = Enum('ClientType_ENUM', ClientType_DICT)
print(int(ClientType_ENUM('webapp').name))

@app.post("/example")
def login(device_type: ClientType_ENUM):
    deviceType = int(device_type.name) # print 1
```