# Enum function to map value to a related value

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Currently, I have an enum that represents a name/number mapping. Each EventType, however, also has additional "related properties" (e.g. a status code, and a message type).

```
class EventType(Enum):
  CANCELLED = 0
  ONTIME = 1
  DELAYED = 2

  def get_status(self):
    if self == EventType.CANCELLED:
        return "statuscode1"
    elif self == EventType.DELAYED:
        return "statuscode2"
    else:
        return "statuscode3"

  def get_message_type(self):
    if self == EventType.CANCELLED:
        return "messagetype1"
    elif self == EventType.DELAYED:
        return "messagetype2"
    else:
        return "messagetype3"
```

Instead of creating the methods above and tons of if chains checking against self, is there a cleaner way of refactoring to return the status codes and message types? It's almost as if `CANCELLED = (0, statuscode1, messagetype1)`.. How can I represent this concept in an enum? Is an enum even the correct way to do this?

Comment: How is it a duplicate question?  I already have code that represents an enum in the OP...

Comment: I think it is duplicate because if you see some of the top answers of that question, you can find ways to implement enum in python.

Comment: @MrAlihoseiny:  The OP is not asking how to *implement* an enum type, but how to *use* the existing `Enum` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the value of the `Enum` member to be `0`, `1`, or `2`, then you will need to either override `__new__`, or use `aenum`.

Using the `aenum` library<sup>1</sup>:

```
from aenum import MultiValueEnum

class EventType(MultiValueEnum):
    _init_ = 'value status message'
    CANCELLED = 0, 'status1', 'message1'
    ONTIME = 1, 'status2', 'message2'
    DELAYED = 2, 'status3', 'message3'
```

and in use:

```
>>> print(EventType.ONTIME)
EventType.ONTIME
>>> print(EventType.ONTIME.value)
1
>>> print(EventType.ONTIME.status)
status2
>>> print(EventType.ONTIME.message)
message2
```

See [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964875/208880) for an example of how to do this with the stdlib Enum (which uses the overriding `__new__` technique).

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Ended up going with this approach. The other approach is nice and clean as well but this approach seemed a bit easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.4, there is a new [Enum data type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), which you can use as:

```
class EventType(Enum):

    def __init__(self, id, code, message):
        self.id = id
        self.code = code
        self.message = message

    CANCELLED = 1, 'code1', 'message1'
    ONTIME = 2, 'code2', 'message2'
    DELAYED = 3, 'code3', 'message3'
```

To use, simply:

```
EventType.CANCELLED.code # returns 'message1'
```

If it's just the use case you described, you can also use named tuple if you want:

```
from collections import namedtuple

    Event = namedtuple('event', ['id', 'code', 'message'])
    
    class EventType:
        CANCELLED = Event(1, 'code1', 'message1')
        ONTIME = Event(2, 'code2', 'message2')
        DELAYED = Event(3, 'code3', 'message3')
```

To use this one:

```
EventType.CANCELLED # return event(id=1, code='code1', message='message1')
EventType.CANCELLED.message # return message1
```

Comment: Good use of `__init__`.  If the OP needs the values to be `0`, `1`, and `2`, though, you should override `__new__` instead.  See [`my other answere here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964875/208880) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tuple as the value of your `Enum` objects, and include the status and message strings together with the integer code. Then you can add methods (or `property` descriptors) to fetch individual pieces of the tuple via the `value` attribute:

```
class EventType(Enum):
   CANCELLED = 0, "status1", "message1"
   ONTIME = 1, "status2", "message2"
   DELAYED = 2, "status3", "message3"

   @property
   def code(self):
       return self.value[0]

   @property
   def status(self):
       return self.value[1]

   @property
   def message(self):
       return self.value[2]

print(EventType.CANCELLED.message) # prints "message3"
```

Comment: Neat!  This method does leave `member.value` as the tuple instead of the `int`, though.

Comment: I'm going to try this method, as well as the aenum method answer above. Thank you both!